# Dynamically assign value to span on view from controller in codeigniter using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

My Code is here

Controller:

```
echo '<span id="remain_casual">'.$total_casual_leave.'</span>'.'<span id="remain_sick">'.$no_of_sick_leaves.'</span>';
```

View:

```
<td align="center"><span id="remain_casual"><?php echo ""; ?></span></td>
<td align="center"><span id="remain_sick"><?php echo ""; ?></span></td>
```

When I check using firebug addons then I am getting values but it is not going to display on ui. If someone is here then please sort it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. And your controller should not be echoing HTML, that's what a view is for.

Comment: Please read About `view` on codeigniter, your missing some basics here.

Comment: can you please provide the jquery function used.

Answer (score 0):

You have done same thing twice.No need to do that.Just load the values in Controller.Use a data array.
echo ''.$total_casual_leave.''.''.$no_of_sick_leaves.'';

```
$data=array(
'total_casual_leave'=>'VLUE OF CASUAL LEAVE',
'no_of_sick_leaves'=>'VALUE OF STOCKS'
);
```

Then load the relevant view along with the data

```
$this->load->view('YOUR VIEW',$data);
```

Then in the view so like this

```
<td align="center"><span id="remain_casual"><?php echo $total_casual_leave;?></span> </td>
<td align="center"><span id="remain_sick"><?php echo $no_of_sick_leaves; ?></span></td>
```

This should print your values nicely in the view.